# php paginate recordset with order by random

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mySQL recordset of business that i have to randomise the order to be fair to them to make sure they all get the same exposure.

My problem now is the list is too long so I have to paginate the results. I cannot use the limit LIMIT %d, %d with the way I randomise the records because it re-randomises the records and sometimes the same businesses appear.

What I need is to get the records in a random order and then paginate through them. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

```
SELECT * 
FROM business
ORDER BY RAND( ) 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I know RAND( ) is not the most efficient way to randomise records. I will change this afterwards.

Comment: [Google is your friend](http://www.google.com/search?q=paginate+order+by+rand) - [first result](http://nyrodev.info/en/posts/186/PHP-MySQL-Howto-paged-with-a-random-order) addresses exactly your problem.

Comment: Whilst that is a very good method, it's worth noting that the order will remain the same for as long as the key is stored in the session. It may be wise to recreate the key when the user accesses the first page, so that there is more randomisation on a per user basis but they will still see all the results if they proceed to page 2,3 etc

Comment: thanks for that. I had googled it but could see nothing of use. Must have missed this one

Comment: RAND() is not a static number. So it called rand.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do the pagination purely through jquery?

This would keep the list in the same order until the page is reloaded and re-randomised.